# Cumulative scaling of graphics for animation

Tags: javascript, animation, graphics, scale, paperjs

I'm trying to write a small javascript library to help animating transformations on shapes using paper.js, but unforuntately this kind of graphics/maths is not a key strength of mine!

I've been able to implement simple transformations, such as translate and rotate, by making small transformations each frame, but I can't work out the maths to cumulatively scale a shape.

For example, the rough pseudocode version of my translate animation code:

```
function rotateAnimation(shape, degrees, timeSecs) {
    var anglePerSecond = degrees / timeSecs,
        duration = timeSecs;
    shape.onFrame = function(e) {
        var timePassedSinceLastFrame = e.delta, // in seconds
            rotateAmount = anglePerSecond * timePassedSinceLastFrame;
         shape.rotate(rotateAmount);
         duration -= timePassedSinceLastFrame;
    }
}
```

I can't work out how to make this kind of approach work for scaling though as I don't know how to calculate the scale amount each frame. If anyone has any advice at all on this it'd be greatly appreciated! If you want to look at the actual code, rather than my bastardized pseudocode above, it's on github: https://github.com/jordanwallwork/paper.animate/blob/master/paper.animate.js

Edit: am also having the same issue with shearing!

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this in the end was rather than calculating the scale/shear at incremental steps, to perform the transformation to calculate the desired result, and then to simply animate each point separately using the translation code i'd already written